# Как сделать клик по ссылке?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Так же, как бы это было, если бы нажал пользователь для кнопки:

```
<button id="saveEdit" class="alllist" style="float:left; margin-right:10px">Save</button>
```

**Обновление**

Нужно вызвать это событие без участия пользователя:

```
$(document).on("click", '#saveEdit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Editor.saveform(this);
});
```

Comment: Что вы хотите?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#saveEdit').trigger('click');
```

Учитесь пользоваться гуглом.