# Как выполнить клик по ссылке с помощью Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Доброго времени суток.
Имеется код:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1;URL=http://site.ru"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    document.location='http://site.ru';
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Загружается сайт (к примеру site.ru). На нем имеется ссылка. Вида

```
<a href="http://site2.ru">http://site2.ru</a>
```

Можно ли как то выполнить клик по этой ссылке при загрузке вышестоящего кода?
Спасибо заранее.

Comment: напишите для каких целей это нужно. возможно это пригодится http://jdevelop.info/articles/html-css-js/200-perekhod-na-druguyu-stranitsu-s-pomoshchyu-javascript

Comment: генерация событий на элементах https://learn.javascript.ru/dispatch-events

Answer (score 3):

В JS Можно не только назначать обработчики на события, но и генерировать их самому. При этом событие срабатывает наравне с браузерными, то есть обычные браузерные обработчики на него отреагируют. Например:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('elem');
var event = new Event("click");
  setInterval(function(){
     elem.dispatchEvent(event);
  },5000);
  elem.addEventListener('click', function(){console.log('click')});
```

```html
<button id="elem">Автоклик</button>
```

**P.S.** все же рекомендую перед тем как создать вопрос, использовать поиск.
[Как сделать клик по ссылке?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/362252/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b5?rq=1)